# Can "wall of text comments" be flagged?

Tags: support, moderators, comments, flagging

What is the moderators' stance on wall-o-text consecutive comments from a single-user (single as in per thread, not a particular individual)?

There's a reason why the comments are character limited.

I've seen it happen from more than one user, so it isn't anyone in particular, and despite not being the post author of those, it is annoying to see (too much noise compared to what SE intended), possibly even more annoying to the post owners.

"If something is so big, post a separate answer", is what comes to mind, and if you have, then *why?!*

Comment: I don't like 'em either, but sometimes, what you have to say is _not_ an answer, but takes more than the 600 characters allotted to a comment. (Of course, that's having a _lot_ to say, but if you're including some links, 600 characters can disappear quickly.)

Comment: Comments are ephemeral, and can be deleted, and can be moved to a chat room (which will disappear too), and should not change/modify the question and/or the answer but only to ask/provide clarification.